# D3 array object format not being picked up

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to get D3 to understand an array within an object so that D3 recognises there are two elements to be created one for 10 and one for 6.

If I have a standard array e.g. var myobj = [10,6];
D3 understands this fine and creates two elements. However, D3 will not do this if an array is embedded inside an object like below. My question is a) why does D3 not understand this?  b) how can I make d3 understand that I want two elements created? I have looked at d3.nested() but I don't understand it.

grateful for any help

```
var myobj = 
    [
        {myarray:[10,6]}

    ];

  xx.selectAll(".newrec")
                .data(myobj)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                    .attr("class","newrec")
                    .attr("width",function (d) {return d.myarray;  }) //for width D3 returns one element rectangle with width of "10,6" which is not a width!
                    ;
```

Comment: If it's just this one array, why don't you simply: `.data(myobj[0].myarray)` and then `.attr("width",function (d) {return d;  })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your data structure you could do something like:

```
var myobj = [ {myarray:[10,6,7]} ];

d3.selectAll(".newrec")
    .data(myobj[0].myarray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","newrec")
    .attr("width",function (d) {console.log(d); return d});
```

That will create 3 `rects` with the appropriate widths, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/f3vqp7ct/

Answer (score 1):

To understand how D3 handles this data:

```
var myobj = 
[
    {myarray:[10,6]}

];

console.log(myobj);
```

When you go to your browser:

[image]

You are can see that `myobj` is an object with an object inside and some properties (e.g. length).

Now break that object down into its parts:

```
console.log(myobj);
console.log(myobj[0]);
console.log(myobj[0].myarray);
console.log(myobj[0].myarray[0]);
```

And the browser:

[image]

This should hopefully help you understand your first question and I think it will make the rest begin to make sense. Keep this in mind: you can think about all (most?) data and var in D3 as objects.

I think this is a good example of how to use `d3.nest`, if you would like to:

Have a `trial.csv` file

```
position,value
"Outer",100
"Inner",10
"Inner",6
```

"Outer" and "inner" are demonstrating nesting positions.

Now nest - key by "position" and then sum the "values" of each key (you probably want to do something else besides sum):

```
d3.csv("trial.csv", function(error, csv_data) {
    var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.position; })
        .rollup(function(d) {
            return d3.sum(d, function(i) { return i.value; });
        }).entries(csv_data);

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(data[1]);
})
```

Head to the browser:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is really useful, and is aiding my understanding of D3 as well as JavaScript! Sometimes it's really useful to have one long array in one object rather than making millions of objects to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it in other way.

```
var myarray = 
[
    {myObject:10, ...},
    {myObject:6, ...}
];

xx.selectAll(".newrec")
            .data(myobj)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("class","newrec")
                .attr("width",function (d, i) {return d.myarray[i].myObject;  }) //for width D3 returns one element rectangle with width of "10,6" which is not a width!
                ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the way you suggest is the standard way. However, I don't want to keep redefining 'myobject' 50 times. It's much easier to define it once and have an array attached which d3 can interpret. Do you think it's not possible even though D3 can interpret arrays

Comment: i see. i think d3.data is designed to process row by row, and you would like have something that can process column by column. i dont think d3 can do that directly. you either modify the lib... or use a row by row approache. if you dont want to modify your data structure, i prefer to append the elements seperately. e.g.  .data(myObj.myArray1).enter().append(sth).... .data(myObj.myArray2).enter().select(sth).